# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' on line

Tags: php, html

Me and my mate we're trying to solve this for over 1.5 hours, we are still getting the same and tried almost everything we could.
Could anyone help us do that? ,This is error what we're getting:

> ( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in C:\aboamirtbk\www\edit.php on line 141

Thanks to everyone who will help. :)

```
<html>
<body>
<center>


<?php include("table_php().php"); 

if(!empty($_SESSION['LoggedIn0']) && !empty($_SESSION['student_number']))
{
?>
<br><br>
<?php
     include "base.php";
 // Check connection
 if (mysqli_connect_errno())
   {
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
   }
   $username = $_SESSION['student_number'];
  if ($result = $con->query("SELECT * FROM students WHERE students.student_number = '".$username."'"))
                        {
                                if ($result->num_rows > 0)
                                {   
                                    echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='10'>";
                                        echo " <tr> <th><font color=red size=5>שם</font></th>  <th><font color=red size=5>שם משפחה</font></th> <th><font color=red size=5>סיסמה</font></th> <th><font color=red size=5>דואר אלקטרוני</font></th><th><font color=red size=5>Edit</font></th> </tr>";
                                        while ($row = $result->fetch_object())
                                        {
                                                echo "<tr>";

                                                //echo "<td>" . $row->ID. "</td>";<th>ID</th>

                                                echo "<td>" . $row->student_name . "</td>";
                                                echo "<td>" . $row->student_last . "</td>";
                                                echo "<td> Can't Show</td>";
                                                echo "<td>" . $row->student_email . "</td>";
                                                echo "<td><a href='edit1.php?id=" . $row->student_name . "'>Edit</a></td>";
                                            //    echo "<td><a href='delswim.php?id=" . $row->student_name . "'>Delete</a></td>";
                                                echo "</tr>";
                                        }

                                        echo "</table><br>";

                                }
                                else
                                {
                                        echo "No results to display!";
                                }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                                echo "Error: " . $con->error;
                        }
                        if ($result2 = $con->query("SELECT * FROM students WHERE students.student_number = '".$username."'"))
                        echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='10'>";
                                        echo " <tr> <th><font color=red size=5>מספר סטודנט</font></th>  <th><font color=red size=5>מוסד לימוד</font></th> <th><font color=red size=5>כתובת סטודנט</font></th> </tr>";
                                        while ($row2 = $result2->fetch_object())
                                        {
                                                echo "<tr>";

                                                //echo "<td>" . $row->ID. "</td>";<th>ID</th>

                                                echo "<td>" . $row2->student_number . "</td>";
                                                echo "<td>" . $row2->student_collage . "</td>";
                                              //  echo "<td> Can't Show</td>";
                                                echo "<td>" . $row2->student_address . "</td>";
                                              //  echo "<td><a href='edit1.php?id=" . $row->student_name . "'>Edit</a></td>";
                                            //    echo "<td><a href='delswim.php?id=" . $row->student_name . "'>Delete</a></td>";
                                                echo "</tr>";
                                        }

                                        echo "</table>";
                        $con->close();


                ?>


</center>
</body>
</html>

                        <?php
} elseif(!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password']))
      $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['username']);
    $password = md5(mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['password']));
    $id_student = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['id_student']);


    $checklogin = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `students` WHERE student_number = '".$username."' AND password = '".$password."' AND id_student= '".$id_student."'");
    $check_var = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM groups WHERE student_number = '".$username."'");
    $_SESSION['LoggedIn0'] = 1;

    $checklogin = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `students` WHERE student_number = '".$username."' AND password = '".$password."' AND id_student= '".$id_student."'");
    $check_var = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM groups WHERE student_number = '".$username."'");

    if(mysqli_num_rows($checklogin) == 1)
    {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($checklogin);
             $row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($check_var);
        $email = $row['student_name'];
        $id = $row['id_student'];
        $studentlast = $row['student_last'];
        $email1 = $row['student_email'];
        $birth = $row['student_datebirth'];
        $last = $row['last'];
        $student_address = $row['student_address'];
        $student_collage = $row['student_collage'];
        $_SESSION['id_student'] =$id;

        $_SESSION['student_number'] = $username;
      $_SESSION['last'] = $last;
        $_SESSION['student_name'] = $email;
        $_SESSION['student_last'] = $studentlast;
        $_SESSION['student_email'] = $email1;
        $_SESSION['student_datebirth'] = $birth;
        $_SESSION['student_address'] = $student_address;
        $_SESSION['student_collage'] = $student_collage;

    $_SESSION['LoggedIn0'] = 1;

        echo "<h1>&#1492;&#1510;&#1500;&#1495;&#1514;&#1501; &#1500;&#1492;&#1514;&#1495;&#1489;&#1512; &#1500;&#1508;&#1512;&#1493;&#1508;&#1497;&#1500; &#1513;&#1500;&#1499;&#1501; </h1>";
        echo "<p>&#1488;&#1504;&#1488; &#1492;&#1502;&#1514;&#1503; , &#1500;&#1492;&#1499;&#1497;&#1503; &#1488;&#1514; &#1504;&#1514;&#1493;&#1504;&#1497;&#1498; &#1489;&#1508;&#1512;&#1493;&#1508;&#1497;&#1500;..</p>";
        echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='2;index.php' />";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<h1>&#1492;&#1499;&#1504;&#1505;&#1514; &#1504;&#1514;&#1493;&#1504;&#1497;&#1501; &#1500;&#1488; &#1504;&#1499;&#1493;&#1504;&#1497;&#1501;</h1>";
        echo "<p><strong>&#1514;&#1489;&#1491;&#1493;&#1511; &#1492;&#1505;&#1497;&#1489;&#1493;&#1514; &#1492;&#1489;&#1488;&#1493;&#1514; :</strong></p>";
          echo "<ol start='1' type='1'>";
          echo "<li>1. &#1502;&#1505;&#1508;&#1512; &#1494;&#1492;&#1493;&#1514; / &#1502;&#1505;&#1508;&#1512; &#1505;&#1496;&#1493;&#1491;&#1504;&#1496; / &#1505;&#1497;&#1505;&#1502;&#1492; &#1513;&#1490;&#1493;&#1497;&#1497;&#1501;</li>";
            echo "<li>&nbsp  &nbsp  &nbsp  &nbsp  &nbsp  2. &#1497;&#1513; &#1514;&#1511;&#1500;&#1492; &#1489;&#1513;&#1512;&#1514; &#1513;&#1500; &#1488;&#1514;&#1512; , &#1493;&#1514;&#1489;&#1491;&#1493;&#1511; &#1489;&#1494;&#1502;&#1503; &#1488;&#1495;&#1512; &#1489;&#1489;&#1511;&#1513;&#1492;.</li>";
              echo "<li>&nbsp  &nbsp  &nbsp  &nbsp  &nbsp &nbsp  &nbsp  &nbsp  &nbsp  &nbsp  &nbsp  &nbsp  &nbsp &nbsp  &nbsp &nbsp  &nbsp  &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp 3. &#1514;&#1489;&#1491;&#1493;&#1511; &#1502; CAPS LOCK &#1489;&#1502;&#1511;&#1500;&#1491;&#1514; &#1513;&#1500;&#1498; , &#1488;&#1501; &#1499;&#1514;&#1489;&#1514; &#1504;&#1499;&#1493;&#1503; &#1489;&#1513;&#1496;&#1495; &#1513;&#1500; &#1505;&#1497;&#1505;&#1502;&#1492; &#1488;&#1493; &#1500;&#1488; .</li>";
                echo "<li>&nbsp  &nbsp  &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp  &nbsp &nbsp 4. &#1492;&#1495;&#1513;&#1489;&#1493;&#1503; &#1513;&#1500;&#1498; &#1504;&#1506;&#1493;&#1500; &#1500;&#1508;&#1497; &#1492;&#1490;&#1491;&#1512;&#1492; &#1492;&#1504;&#1493;&#1492;&#1500; , &#1500;&#1498; &#1500;&#1502;&#1494;&#1499;&#1497;&#1512;&#1493;&#1514; &#1513;&#1500;&#1499;&#1501;.</li>";
                  echo "<li>5. &#1492;&#1508;&#1512;&#1502;&#1496;&#1512; &#1513;&#1500; &#1512;&#1493;&#1493;&#1496;&#1512; 10.0.0.2 &#1513;&#1490;&#1493;&#1497; &nbsp &nbsp  &nbsp  &nbsp &nbsp  </li>";
                    echo "<li>6. &#1514;&#1504;&#1505;&#1492; &#1506;&#1493;&#1491; &#1508;&#1506;&#1501;  &#1491;&#1512;&#1498;  <a href=\"index.php\">&#1499;&#1488;&#1503;</a>. &nbsp  &nbsp  &nbsp  &nbsp  &nbsp  &nbsp &nbsp  &nbsp  &nbsp  &nbsp &nbsp  </li>";

                    echo "</ol>";
           /*      echo "<br><h3 align='center'> &#1511;&#1493;&#1491; &#1513;&#1490;&#1497;&#1497;&#1492; : &#1514;&#1511;&#1500;&#1492; &#1502;&#1488;&#1490;&#1512; &#1504;&#1514;&#1493;&#1504;&#1497;&#1501; 501 </h3>";           
            */
    }
}
else
{

    include "die.php";

}


?>
```

Comment: And line 141 is which line?

Comment: It could be that you simply forgot an opening curly brace after the `elseif` in the middle of that code section you posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have missed opening brace of elesif added at line no 84

```
                            <?php
    } elseif(!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password']))
{ // you missed opening brace here
```

Comment: Seriously? Just put what you've changed, where and why rather than another monster code-dump.

Comment: Thanks for reminding, I was editing answer but had system issue

Comment: This is a common question and should be closed as a duplicate. It should not be answered. In the future please flag a as duplicate only.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add opening curly brace for else if . Please check below modification:

.
.
.

```
<?php
} elseif(!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password'])) {
      $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['username']);
    $password = md5(mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['password']));
```

.
.
.

Comment: This is a common question and should be closed as a duplicate. It should not be answered. In the future please flag a as duplicate only.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the caused of the problem

```
if ($result2 = $con->query("SELECT * FROM students WHERE students.student_number = '".$username."'"))
```

There are no curly brackets of that condition.

Comment: Doesn't need to be with that one - technically the whole line is `if ($result2 = $con->query("SELECT * FROM students WHERE students.student_number = '".$username."'")) echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='10'>";`

Comment: Yeah thats right but when it comes to that kind of lots of if else statements it is better to wrap them up it curly brackets so that it will not confusing. but thanks.

Comment: This is a common question and should be closed as a duplicate. It should not be answered. In the future please flag a as duplicate only.